# protractor getting value from date picker input box

Tags: datepicker, protractor

I'm using a date picker plugin called angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

html:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="true" ng-required="true" name="startDate"
 data-ng-model="source" class="input-large date-time-select-input ng-pristine
 ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" date-time-text-field="" 
 required="required" disabled="disabled">
```

when the page loads, a date is populated in the box. I can't get the value from this textbox.

I tried:

```
element(by.name("startDate")).getAttribute('value'); //returns null
element(by.name("startDate")).getText(); //returns empty string
```

Comment: Are you sure there no iframes on the page and there is only one element with name="startDate"? Also, both of the expressions you've presented return promises - how have you verified that there are null and empty string returned?

Comment: @alecxe there are no iframes. I used this to verify: `DisputeQueueSearchPage.startDateTextbox.getAttribute('value').then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

So I had asked dev to add in an `id` attribute, then I was able to locate it via `id` and do -

```
DisputeQueueSearchPage.startDateTextbox.getAttribute('value').then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
});
```

this works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
await this.shipmentEndDateInFilter.getAttribute('value').then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
})
```

Works for me as well on fetching the by the default value of the date textbox.